# Getting to class variable from instance of Class in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I have a class like this:

```
class Cow
  @feet : 4

  constructor: (@name) ->

bes = new Cow "Bessie"
```

The question is, is it possible to access feet only given `bes`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to get at the class and there you will find your `feet`:

```
class Cow
    @feet: 4
    constructor: (@name) ->

class HexaCow extends Cow
    @feet: 6

bes = new Cow('Bessie')
pan = new HexaCow('Pancakes')

alert(bes.constructor.feet) # 4
alert(pan.constructor.feet) # 6
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZfsqP/

I don't know of any special CoffeeScript replacement for `constructor` though.